# After a != null check I still get "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

Tags: typescript

Given `message.text: string | undefined` I check for `nil`  and go on with my code assuming that TS inferred the new type to `string`. You can see that it does when I do `const text = message.text`.

The type check fails when I call `regExp.test(message.text)` and I can't explain why. This function is sync, mutability is not possible. What am I missing?

You can fiddle around the [TS playground I created](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKwIA9gB+ALinmACcBLAOxSgF8AoZgYwHtaKoBXSgDYBJFLQ6UIAGWo9MAbWZQoAeiTKANIpUAjDVuVtlzALqtO3YOQAWHXgIAmABUoc2CeHESoMUABQBbd28yT2Q0AEoodAA+bC1qADM-QK80ADo8QijMWjsBSKwtJQlgflooBKQBeAgtFnikgKD0zOA0iiRKYHgAdWpgK18AAwBCIfCCoqgSstxKXlqleqVlZSgAdysQKHsOBFwrGVxwaDYrCDYAawqkagEiBr9+YVFxKRk2+A5A318JFAAovgwJEYtMIIDgRkEMAmqkINDCBNJkpihBSpRypVqosmKwVmsBkcjgk6NAkPAoEIoARIGw8PYtOYeK0olAUmEEa1Hr5niIxBJpBR2t8IL9-kCQVFYhKoXgKL5Wsi4qjwRisVUanV8WrZlQFsxGEA)

```
type Message = { text?: string }

const urlIgnoreList = [
  /a/,
  /b/,
  /c/
]

const shouldProcessMessage = (message: Message) => {
  if (message.text == null) {
    return false
  }

  if (message.text.startsWith(`!`)) {
    return false
  }

  // why does this type check fail?
  if (urlIgnoreList.some((regExp) => regExp.test(message.text))) {
    return false
  }

  // this is fine as I expected
  const text = message.text
  if (urlIgnoreList.some((regExp) => regExp.test(text))) {
    return false
  }

  return true
}
```

TS Error on line 19:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Typescript does not track related variable, that's why you are seeing this issue. There is a detailed discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Bottomline, it is difficult to track a related variable that's why it's not a feature.

Comment: @Nishant why am I allowed to call `message.text.startsWith(`!`)` at line 14 then?

Answer (score 1):

My guess: In your callback, you are outside of flow analysis. That callback could be executed at any later point in time and any code outside of this function could re-assign `undefined` to `message.text` again. *We* know that won't happen, but TS doesn't.

Easiest workaround? Assign `message.text` to a `const text = message.text` and work with that. That cannot be mutated so TS can track it for sure.

Comment: It's a bug either way because it allows me to call `message.text.startsWith`. I think it has to do with `regExp.test()`. It thinks it can mutate `message.text`.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve error on line 19, you need to replace just declaration of Message.

Here is the update for it

REPLACE

```
type Message = { text?: string }
```

BY

```
type Message = { text: string }
```